# Mustache: Specifying tag only be pulled from child, not parent

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have some data where sub-items have the same properties as the parent item. Mustache gets confused when I use tags for those properties within the sub item, sometimes pulling from the parent.

Here's the data:

```
{
  "menus":[
    {
      "title":"Food",
      "slug":"Food",
      "sections":[
        {
          "title":"Soup & Salad",
          "type":"section",
          "desc":"Dressing Choices: Hidden Valley Ranch®, Creamy Bleu Cheese, ...",
          "items":[
            {
              "title":"Sesame Ginger Chicken & Quinoa Salad",
              "name":"sesame-ginger-chicken--quinoa-salad",
              "type":"item",
              "desc":"fresh spring and baby spinach mix ..."
            },
            {
              "title":"Add to Any Salad",
              "name":"add-to-any-salad",
              "type":"item",
              "desc":null
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};
```

And the Mustache template:

```
{{#menus}}
  <div id="menu_{{slug}}" class="Menu-Container">
    <h1 class="Section-Title">{{{title}}}</h1>

    {{#desc}}<p class="menu_desc desc">{{{desc}}}</p>{{/desc}}

    <div class="Menu Tabs">
      {{#sections}}
      <section id="section_{{id}}" class="Menu-Section">
        <h2 class="title">{{{title}}}</h2>

        {{#desc}}<p class="section_desc">{{{desc}}}</p>{{/desc}}

        {{#items}}
        <dl class="menuItem">
        <dt class="item_title">{{{title}}}</dt>
        {{#desc}}<dd class="item_description">{{{desc}}}</dd>{{/desc}}
        </dl>
        {{/items}}
      </section>
      {{/sections}}
    </div>
  </div>
{{/menus}}
```

And here's the output:

```
<div id="menu_Food" class="Menu-Container">
  <h1 class="Section-Title">Food</h1>
  <section id="section_s5005429" class="Menu-Section">
      <h2 class="title">Soup &amp; Salad</h2>
      <p class="section_desc">Dressing Choices: Hidden Valley Ranch®, Creamy
          Bleu Cheese, ...</p>
      <dl class="menuItem">
          <dt class="item_title">Sesame Ginger Chicken &amp; Quinoa Salad</dt>
          <dd class="item_description">fresh spring and baby spinach mix ...</dd>
      </dl>
      <dl class="menuItem">
          <dt class="item_title">Add to Any Salad</dt>
          <dd class="item_description">Dressing Choices: Hidden Valley Ranch®,
              Creamy Bleu Cheese, ...</dd>
      </dl>
  </section>
</div>
```

For the last item, "Add to Any Salad", with the `desc` property set to `null`, Mustache inserts the `desc` from the parent `section`. Is there a way to specify for Mustache to only use the `desc` property from the `item`, not its parent `section`?

Comment: why use the block {{#desc}} ? won't just {{{desc}}} work? or, if you use the blocks, then just {{{.}}} should work. also, you can use an empty block IF and inject default markup in the case of desc being null.

Comment: I don't want it to add the `<dd>` if there isn't a `{{desc}}`, hence the block. Yes `{{.}}` works, I just had the `{{desc}}` there out of habit.

Comment: i see the problem now, and i couldn't find a work around. i even tried partials and overloading. to fix it, you can either modify the mustache file, specifically the "Context.prototype.lookup()" routine to avoid the "context = context.parent;" part. or, you can change your data before feeding it to the template to remove ambiguous names or insert smoking guns that you can use to trigger empty block behavior.

Comment: @dandavis Yeah, I was hoping to get around that. If I set null `desc` properties to just whitespace, it at least leaves the child's `<dd>` empty.

Comment: i guess you could also hard-code each visible item slot to avoid iterating items.  {{#items}} {{#desc}}  becomes {{#items.0.desc}}, which you can skip over without ambiguity. if you always only have one or two items that's feasible, but i wouldn't want to maintain {{#items.32.desc}}...

Comment: @dandavis The number of items is highly variable, so that wouldn't be a great solution. Besides, I thought with Mustache you weren't able to reference indexes like that? Too "logic-y" or something.

Comment: indexing works: http://jsfiddle.net/Bf38c/17/ , as do properties like {{items.length}}, you can use ".length" to sniff out null vs ""

Comment: i figured out a way around your problem with a pretty simple function: http://jsfiddle.net/Bf38c/19/ . it does depend on your data not containing ":null," or ":null}" as a weird string. it adds a ms or two to the render time, but it preserves your other logic and code, uses unmodified mustache features, prevents the empty <dd>, is a 1-line patch, and allows more modification if needed by cloning data so that patches won't float upstream. if this is something that comfortably uses mustache time anyway, then the additional json.parse() time will be negligible.

Comment: Ah, great. That's basically what I ended up doing, though I'm already doing some processing of the data so I can easily do the check for `null` in there. Perhaps instead of an empty string, `false` would be better and accomplishes the intended effect in Mustache. Go ahead and post this as an answer and I'll mark it as the solution.